# Why does this condition on AR coefficients imply a unit root?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, unit-root

Consider an AR($q$) process:

$$ X_t-\theta_1 X_{t-1}-...-\theta_q X_{t-q}=Z_t $$

where $Z_t$~$WN(0,1)$.

Why does the following condition on the process's coefficients imply a unit root:

$$ \theta_1+\theta_2+...+\theta_q=1? $$

Comment: I edited the question quite considerably. If you dislike the result, feel free to undo the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of root is an $x$ that satisfies

$$x^t - \theta_1 x^{t-1} - \cdots - \theta_q x^{t-q} = 0$$

If the given condition holds, then

$$1 - \theta_1 -  \cdots - \theta_q = 0$$

which means that $x=1$ satisifies

$$x^t - \theta_1 x^{t-1} - \cdots - \theta_q x^{t-q} = 0$$

so $x=1$ is a root, as required.